# What are different types of Entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I know how Entity Framework works and hear lot about POCO type or complex Types. But in all What are the different types of Entities available in Entity Framework?

Comment: That's a broad question. The word entity derives from its database orgins: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model EF's support is described here at a high level: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Types-of-Entities.aspx

Comment: Entities? This is more of a conceptual term. Entities are nothing but objects of certain types like all other objects.